# Typescript: How to make array.indexOf case insensitive search

Tags: angular, typescript

This below code(`forbiddenNames` method) is working for case sensitive only. But i want to make it working for case insensitive too. How to make this working?

E.g. 
If search text "ashutosh"(instead of "Ashutosh")then also it should able search in array `forbiddenUsernames`

---

CODE

template:

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username">
```

Class

```
 forbiddenUsernames = ['Chris', 'Ashutosh'];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNames.bind(this)]) 
    });
  }


// validator is just a function, its our own validator
  forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (this.forbiddenUsernames.indexOf(control.value)  !== -1 ) { //  "-1" -  did not find a match
      return { 'nameIsForbidden' : true };
    }
  }
```

> Case sensitive case

[image: Case sensitive case]

```
Case In-sensitive case
```

[image: Case In-sensitive case]
Please let me know if question is not clear, i will explain you

Comment: convert to lowercase and compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider making the forbidden names either complete upperCase or complete lowerCase. And then do the needful when comparing;

Something like :

```
forbiddenUsernames = ['chris', 'ashutosh'];


ngOnInit() {
  this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
    'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNames.bind(this)])
  });
}


// validator is just a function, its our own validator
forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): {
  [s: string]: boolean
} {
  if (control.value && this.forbiddenUsernames.indexOf(control.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) { //  "-1" -  did not find a match
    return {
      'nameIsForbidden': true
    };
  }
}
```

**Update:**

If your list of forbidden names is coming from a database, you can simply apply a map on the list to get the lowercased list.

```
forbiddenNames = [
  'John',
  'JANE',
  'jacob',
  'SaM',
  'JeReMy',
  'sIdDhArTh'
];

forbiddenNames.map(name => name.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: After adding your suggested code , i am getting error in console: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180831-o8mw-112kb.jpg

Comment: That's because `control.value` is undefined. You can add another check to see if the control.value is defined. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Fine! it works but you have changed this `forbiddenUsernames = ['chris', 'ashutosh'];`  to lowercase.Why?  Actually  forbiddenUsernames  array values  in my application is coming from database, in the database there is uppercase  words also there. , can not we make this working without changing the array?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. I'm not aware of a better way as of now. But I think this is the way it's done in most of the cases like these where exact content needs to be checked. If there was a pattern, you could have used a RegEx. But that's not the case here. So.